# Image not scaling right on iphone 4 and iphone 5 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, image, storyboard

I want to add an image using storyboard to a view that is an edge to edge image. Image width is 640 and height 285. I named the image image@2x.png for iphone 4s and image-568h@2x.png for iphone 5 and added them to the Images.xcassets folder.

On the view in the storyboard I added constraints: 0 on top right and left and some value on down.

When I run iphone 5 simulator I get the following result which is fine:
http://i60.tinypic.com/2lavhgl.png

But the problem is when I run it on 4s it seems like the image shifts up:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2eo8wsz.png

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "some value on down". The 4s screen is shorter, and the bottom constraint is fixed in relation to the bottom of the superview, so you have pushed the bottom of your image view up.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the obvious! Thank you!